# How can I display a Magento Category In WordPress article using fishpig integration?

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, categories, fishpig

I have Magento with **fishpig** integration and **Wordpress** blog.

I can see magento products easy with this shortcode `[product sku="skunumber"]`.

But I have a lot of trouble with categories, how can I display a Magento Category In WordPress article?

There is a shortcode, who can help me to do this Or do I need to code Term Collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these methods

**To display all the Magento categories.**

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**To Display Categories and Subcategories.**

```
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For More Details Visit [DISPLAY CATEGORIES AND SUBCATEGORIES IN MAGENTO](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento/)